# A start job is running for Wait until snapd is fully seeded

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, toshiba

I’m new to Ubuntu and I’m trying to install Ubuntu Server on my toshiba laptop. It’s been hung on this message for the past half hour:

> A start job is running for Wait until snapd is fully seeded (xxxx / no limit)

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Reported unresolved bug, especially for users who do not have **sda** or **sdb**: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1779948

I'd remove the snap service until it's fixed with

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

or change to **snapd 2.33.1+18.04ubuntu2** and **kernel 4.15.0-29-generic**.